# Is there a way to count on a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, duplicates

SQL Server: I need a table with multiple columns, yet it also has a count on a single column which has duplicates. All records are distinct. But I have columns with the same first names. I need a count of all the people with that first name. I want it to display each row with the first name, last name, and customer identifier. I just want to make another field where it counts how many similar first names there are.

Any help would be amazing!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` will give you a solution [like](https://imgur.com/amfIYUC) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl(name) VALUES('A'),('A'),('B'),('A'),('A')

SELECT T1.id, T1.name, count(T2.name) AS 'name count'
from @tbl T1
INNER JOIN @tbl T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
GROUP BY T1.id, T1.name
```

And the output will be like

```
id  name    name count
1   A       4
2   A       4
3   B       1
4   A       4
5   A       4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the fields from your Names table (alias n), joining it to an Aggregate query (alias c) of the FirstName counts.  Something like this:

```
select n.ID, n.FirstName, n.LastName, c.FirstNameCount
from Names n
left outer join
(
    select FirstName, count(*) as FirstNameCount
    from Names
    group by FirstName
) c
on n.FirstName = c.FirstName
```

Note: It's best to do a "left outer join" rather than "inner join" to handle any NULL FirstNames.